# Apache: {IP Address} took too long to respond

Tags: django, apache, server, ip, port

I've installed Apache 2 through the Bitmani Django stack and when I access the localhost it works fine, but when I enter the public IP it loads for a bit and then presents that error.

The apache server is running and I have the conf file set to listen on port 80.

What could be going wrong?